# How to check if column status is null with Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I try for use Google App Script as backend, I have some columns and some columns are not filled so all of them are still output, I want my script to run and output data if all the columns I provided are filled

```
+----+-------+------+
| a  |   b   |  c   |  
+----+-------+------+
| 1  | Item1 | pub  | publish/output
+----+-------+------+
| 2  | Item2 |      | not publish/output
+----+-------+------+
| 3  |       |  pub | not publish/output
+----+-------+------+
```

```
function doGet(e) {
 var page = e.parameter.page || 1;
  var limit = e.parameter.limit || 10;
  var search = e.parameter.search || "";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10S8Igzt1tpqUBgJHVKpny-2s6G3Y3-vFsLMvlZVqpkc/edit#gid=810612111");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("list_film");
  return getUsers(sheet, page, limit, search);
}

function getUsers(sheet, page, limit, search){
  var lowCase = search.toString().toLowerCase();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().filter(([,,c]) => c.toString().toLowerCase().includes(lowCase));
  var dataArray = rows.splice(limit * (page - 1), limit).reduce((ar, [a, b, c, d]) => ar.concat({id: a, year: b, title: c, img: d}), []);
  var jo = {};
  jo.user = dataArray;
  var result = JSON.stringify(jo);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var dataArray = rows.splice(limit * (page - 1), limit).reduce((ar, [a, b, c, d]) => ar.concat({id: a, year: b, title: c, img: d}), []);
```

#### To:

```
var dataArray = rows.splice(limit * (page - 1), limit).reduce((ar, [a, b, c, d]) => {
  if (b != "" && c != "") ar.push({ id: a, year: b, title: c, img: d });
  return ar;
}, []);
```

- In this case, when the cells of columns "B" and "C" have the values, the row is retrieved. But from `{ id: a, year: b, title: c, img: d }`, if you want to check the columns "C" and "D" instead of "B" and "C", please modify `if (b != "" && c != "")` to `if (c != "" && d != "")`.